# Convert JS script into React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to use this simple javascript script (https://seatchart.js.org/ or https://github.com/omarmahili/seatchart.js) in my react application. In a html project, one would only add the script and run it, but I struggle with the integration to the React framework. Any approach suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried some patch work without much success i.e.

1. Calling the JS function from the script in my react component, but "let sc = new Seatchart(options);", provokes a "'Seatchart' is not defined" error.
2. Adding "window" in  "let sc = new window.Seatchart(options); " results in "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null" error at "document.getElementById(options.map.id).appendChild(mapContainer)". (may be because the compiler cannot find "document" which is much realted to html and and not much related to React.)
3. Using UseRef() compiled, but returned a blank screen...

My failling code below omits the entire 1800 lines script which I copied pasted above the React function for "Seatchart()" to be accessed. The script is [here](https://github.com/omarmahili/seatchart.js/blob/develop/src/js/seatchart.js)

```
export default function Tickets () {

    let options = {
        
        map: {
            id: 'map-container',
            rows: 9,
            columns: 9,
            // e.g. Reserved Seat [Row: 1, Col: 2] = 7 * 1 + 2 = 9
            reserved: {
                seats: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
            },
            disabled: {
                seats: [0, 8],
                rows: [4],
                columns: [4]
            }
        },
        types: [
            { type: "regular", backgroundColor: "#006c80", price: 10, selected: [23, 24] },
            { type: "reduced", backgroundColor: "#287233", price: 7.5, selected: [25, 26] }
        ],
        cart: {
            id: 'cart-container',
            width: 280,
            height: 250,
            currency: '£',
        },
        legend: {
            id: 'legend-container',
        },
        assets: {
            path: "../../public",
        }
    };

let sc = new Seatchart(options);

return (
    <div>
        <div id="map-container">
        </div>

        <div id="legend-container">

        </div>
        <div id="shoppingCart-container">

        </div>
    </div>
);
```

}
};

Conceptually, how would I integrate a JS script to my React component?

UPDATE:

In public/index.html:

```
</head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/containers/SeatChart.js" ></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
```

In SeatChart:

```
// SeatChart.js script and Option arg. above, but too long to post...
let sc = new Seatchart(options);
localStorage.setItem("scObj", sc);
localStorage.setItem("test", "this is a test");
console.log("You would see this if SeatChart ran successfully);
```

In Ticket.js

```
export default function Ticket () {
const sc = localStorage.getItem("scObj");
console.log(sc);

const test = localStorage.getItem("test");
console.log(test)

return (
    <div>
        <div>Hello from here!</div>
        <div id="map-container">
        </div>

        <div id="legend-container">

        </div>
        <div id="shoppingCart-container">

        </div>
    </div>
);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. create a js file in your react application in root, say 'init.js', where you import the required script.

now init.js should have access to let sc = new Seatchart(options)

write your required logic, and return/save/dispatch the result to redux store or local storage. (store.dispatch() can be used.)

2.simply import the above`enter code here` script in your index.html file in your react application.

3. In your component, read the output from redux/ local-storage as processed by the script function.

Comment: Thank you!! I implemented the flow, but I have 2 questions:

1) It seems the script is not running at all; No object is created when I add the scripts in the body in public/index.html and reload the page. From my online research, the script should run completely when the index.html is parsed...Am I missing something?

2) What is the logical flow between obtaining the Seatchart object in the Ticket component to executing the "<div id="map-container"> </div>" in the Ticket component? I am missing the logic between getting the object and rendering it via in the div?

Thanks a million!!

Comment: I updated my initial post with snippet from public/index.html and Ticket.js to help visualise the new approach. I know SeatChart.js script is not running because console.log() are not printing and "sc" object in local storage is null...I must be missing something...

Comment: the script is loaded, but it is likely that the function to create object is not invoked. you should enclose the code in IIFE  (// script function to create objec)(). for eg (function(){
let sc = new SeatChart(options)
//other logic
})()


Secondly, the <div id = "map-container> will be placed in a component or in index.html, not in script, script should just give you the object, when you call the function

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Gaurav! After so much research on scripts and our interaction above I much better understand how to use scripts in React! I think your approach is right, but somehow I never managed to get this specific script to work. I managed to get the script to execute the code, but then got stuck on errors about the element not being attached to its element id in the DOM. In the end, I found an open source project that used a roughly similar React component and rebuilt it to my need. Much gratitute for your help!!

Comment: great you figured it out! an upvote to the answer will definitely help!

Comment: I will definetely circle back when I have enough reputation points; I am just getting started on stack overflow and i am not yet allowed to vote! Cheers!